# PrestaShop: How to fix a social share toggle that open in automatic in all products

Tags: prestashop-1.7, socialshare

I entered a toggle for social sharing in the /miniatures/product.tpl but if I click it, it works only in the first product of the page, not in a random single one I want. I tried to fix it changing the .js but in the second way it opens in all products at the same time!

Is there a way to open it in every single product one by one?

I'm using this [toggle](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/353gp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s-icons').click(function() {
        $(this).children('.navbar-nav').toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```